# Отключить все потоки

Tags: windows, kernel, драйвер

Встала следующая задача: есть драйвер и в некоторый момент нужно организовать такую ситуацию, чтобы в системе выполнялся только один поток (текущий). Было сделано: повышался IRQL, каждому процессору (ядру) устанавливалась DPC, в которой вызывается `KeStallExecutionProcessor()`. Когда это все нужно выключить - IRQL понижался. Но проблема в том, что в этом промежутке идет работа с памятью - и я ловил BSOD `IRQL_NOT_LESS_OR_EQUAL` (потому что IRQL высокий). Пока что думаю, можно ли программно из драйвера отключить все ядра, потом включить обратно. Кто, может, сталкивался с такими вопросами?

Comment: У вас ошибка уже в самой постановке вопроса. Почему ваш драйвер вообще волнуют какие-то сторонние потоки? Таких драйверов просто не должно быть ни в одной современной ОС.

Comment: Это вопрос другой, но мне точно это нужно. Я знаю что странно стоит задание, но уверяю, что это необходимо.

Comment: В таком случае вам надо предварительно "залочить" в памяти те страницы, к которым вы будете обращаться при высоком IRQL.

Comment: Если точнее, то я вызываю функцию ZwMapViewOfSection, а в описании у нее стоит IRQL=PASSIVE_LEVEL

Comment: Сначала вызовите эту функцию, а потом меняйте IRQL.

Comment: А мне надо, чтобы в момент вызова этой функции как раз и было все заблокировано.

Comment: Вы желаете невозможного. Расскажите лучше свою реальную задачу.

Comment: Почему? Оно было реализовано, только IRQL остался повышенным. И да, вроде придумал, как это сделать, но в любом случае спасибо за помощь.